# "point.select is not a function" at select events,Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have problem when trying to overide the default behavior for scatter graph point selection to support multiple selection for single mouse left click.

My plotOption is :

```
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            point:{
              events:{
                  click:function(e){
                      var point = this;
                      console.log(point ,"click")
                      point.select(true,true);
                      //e.preventDefault();
                  },
                  select:function(e){
                      var point = this;
                      console.log(point ,"select")
                      point.select(true,true);//just want to select somehow, but got error here
                      //e.preventDefault();// and then prevent the default behavior that will cause unselect of other points.
                  },
                  unselect:function(){
                      var point = this;
                      console.log(point ,"unselect");
                  }
              }
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 3,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series : {
            cursor:'pointer',
            allowPointSelect: true,
            marker:{
                states:{
                    select:{
                        lineWidth:3,
                        lineColor:'#2cbfbe',
                        fillColor:'white',
                        radius:6
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

As you see , I call select(true,false) at both click and select events, but I have  `Uncaught TypeError: point.select is not a function` at select events:

[image]

Comment: isn't the select-callback triggered **when** you call `point.select(true, false)`? Why would you call `point.select` inside that callback again?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4766).

Comment: It seems you are right but I think I can handle it by distinguishing what is I call it dymatically and what is triggered by user. But the problem is it can't be called .